# Visual Studio on Mac OS X

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Can we run Visual Studio on Mac OS X. Actually, I have planned to buy apple mac book pro, but am not sure is Visual Studio IDE work on it or not.

Thanks...

Nirajan

Comment: Are you asking if you can run Visual Studio natively under OSX or are you asking if you can run it using a Virtual Machine under OSX?

Comment: a mac book pro makes a wonderful machine to run Windows on :)

Comment: either way, i'd like to use Visual Studio on apple laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio only runs on Windows, so you would need virtualisation software (VMWare Fusion or Parallels) or Boot Camp. There is WINE which allows some Windows programs to run on OS X, but I doubt you'd want to use it for Visual Studio even if it did work.

Comment: And it looks like people are successfully doing it: http://blog.1530technologies.com/2006/08/visual_studione.html  http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2006/07/20/Anyone-using-Visual-Studio-in-Parallels-on-a-MacBook-Pro_3F00_.aspx  http://forum.parallels.com/thread1788.html

Comment: Run Windows in VMWare Fusion. That's what I do!

Answer (score 3):

Use virtualization software to install windows on MAC and than install visual studio. Another option is monodevelop IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Subjective: I have the latest version of Parallels (that's 5.0) running Windows 7, and I think Visual Studio works fine under this setup.  YMMV.

What's NOT subjective is that you WILL need virtualization software of some sort or another to attempt this.  It doesn't work under WINE.

If you just want to develop .NET framework apps, though, you can install the Mono compilers and use a different IDE (like Eclipse, or MonoDevelop).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set up a virtual machine in the cloud and remote to it.
Thats what I do on my little macbook air.
Here are some instructions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2014/11/21/provision-a-dev-workstation-in-6-minutes-and-0-00.aspx

No need to take up space on your computer.
Personally I switch off the VM when I dont use it so it doesnt cost me anything

Answer (score 0):

visual studio on mac has been launched. Check it [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/).